# Pattern для input number

Tags: javascript, веб-программирование, frontend

Как ограничить ввод положительными числами от 1 до 1000. Регулярное выражение.

```
<input id="bw_calc_users_cnt" type="number" class="form-control" step="1" min="1" max="1000" value="1" title="Bandwidth calculator" pattern="?????????????">
```

Comment: Там вроде и без регулярки всё ограничивается уже атрибутами min и max..

Comment: Да, но вручную я смогу ввести любое значение и больше max и меньше  0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<input id="bw_calc_users_cnt" type="number" class="form-control" step="1" min="1" max="1000" value="1" title="Bandwidth calculator" pattern="([1-9][0-9]{0,2}|1000)">
```